# Detect Keyboard event in MAC

Tags: macos, keyboard

i'm developing a JAVA cross platform software that is essentialy based on AWT and Processing. I'm stuck with an issue about key-responsiveness on MAC: it seems that the AWT canvas can't gain focus -just for keyboard events-.
Is there any software available on MAc that detect the input events of the OS and that says to which window or process they're going to?
Thank you all,
Stefano